# How to store multiple Checkbox State in local-storage in angular

Tags: angularjs, storage, local

I want to populate toggle button using ng-repeat from external JSON data and want to store toggle state of different toggle button in local storage, if user exit app and restart app the last saved state is shown.

View-

```
<ion-toggle ng-repeat="item in category" ng-model="myToggle.checked" ng-change="myToggleChange()">
   {{item.name}} 
</ion-toggle>
```

Controller

```
$scope.myToggleItem = localStorage.getItem('check');

if($scope.myToggleItem){    
  var item = localStorage.getItem('check');  
  $scope.myToggle = {checked: JSON.parse(item)};
  console.log(item);
} else {    
  $scope.myToggle = { checked: true };
}

$scope.myToggleChange = function() {

  angular.forEach($scope.category, function(item){
    if($scope.myToggle.checked == true){
        console.log('Item', $scope.myToggle.checked);
        localStorage.setItem('check', $scope.myToggle.checked);
    }
    if($scope.myToggle.checked == false){
       console.log('Item', $scope.myToggle.checked);
       localStorage.setItem('check', $scope.myToggle.checked);
    }
  });

};
```

plz help how to achieve this thing